# How to export data from Oracle Database to AWS S3 bucket

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have a high voluminous data in my oracle database. I want to migrate it on the AWS S3 bucket. I cannot find a good documentation for this. Please share if someone has already done it.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to use? What type of data do you have? Give more information? What have you tried.  Read: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AWS Data Pipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/)

[Copied from above link]

With AWS Data Pipeline, you can regularly access your data where it’s stored, transform and process it at scale, and efficiently transfer the results to AWS services such as Amazon S3, Amazon RDS, Amazon DynamoDB, and Amazon EMR.

Also found some code on GitHub to backup Oracle data to S3   [link](https://github.com/aws-samples/data-pipeline-samples/tree/master/samples/oracle-backup)

Comment: Can i get the template for s3 to oracle. Not able to find any.